# How to define a Custom Membership Status?

Tags: civimember

Our membership is monthly rolling.
Now We would like to give a member to be in ***Grace period of 12 months*** if they have paid at least for 12 months.

Although I have changed the membership rules to following...[image]

I have also ran the scheduled job after changing the settings, but nothing seems to be changed in terms of status of existing members. Can anyone help please?

EDIT: I have changed the Expired rules to 12 months too, but for example for the person who paid in August 2015 it shows **EXPIRED**, where it should have been **GRACE**

Comment: If you list your membership status rules here, in the order they appear on the Membership Status Rules page and specifying the start & end dates & adjustments for each, that will help to figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, there may be a problem that you are using 'monthly' rolling (i take it you mean 1 month rolling). Does that mean someone needs to have paid for 12 membership cycles? If so there is no way that civicrm currently handles setting Grace to be 12 months based on them having purchased 12 membership cycles. But perhaps that isn't the point.

A more common approach would be as follows, in case this provides some hints to you:

- set a rolling 12 month (1 year) membership
- set Grace to be 12 months starting from End Date and count is as 'current'
- set Expired to start 12 months after End Date
- make sure Grace is above Expired in your order of Member Status.